# Javascript validation doesn't work in my PHP

Tags: php, javascript, validation

I have a simple Javascript validation code that works fine if I send it to a certain PHP address, while it doesn't work if I send it to a PHP page I have created.

The code is quite basic at the moment and validates some fields with regexes.

Basically, if I try it with a given ready-made PHP file (I can't access) it works fine presenting me the error dialog box until all the fields are correct.

Meanwhile, in the PHP page I made, it catches the error, display the dialog box but on the OK alert box click, it submits the fields to my PHP file.

Can someone give me a clue of what's going on?

Thank you.

**This is the Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  // this function calls all the other functions that validate each field of the submitting form
  function validate() {
    var validated = false;
    validated = validateRId() && validateEId();
    return validated;
  }
  // this validates the RID: checking that the field is filled with a number between 1    //and 99999
  function validateRId() {
    var RIdElement =  document.getElementById("RID");
    patternRId = /^([1-9][0-9]{0,4})$/;
    if (patternRId.test(RIdElement.value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert ("Please Enter your RID (a number range 1 to 99999))");
      RIdElement.focus();
      return false
    }
  }
  // this validates the EventID: checking that the field is filled with a number between 1 and 99999
  function validateEId() {
    var EIdElement =  document.getElementById("EID");
    patternEId = /^([1-9][0-9]{0,4})$/;
    if (patternEId.test(EIdElement.value)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      alert ("Please Enter the EID (a number range 1 to 99999))");
      EIdElement.focus();
      return false
    }
  }
  /* ]]> */
</script>
<p/>
  <form action="http://adress.php" method="post" name="submitrunnertime"  onsubmit = "return validate()">
    <table>
      <tr><td>Runner ID*</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="RID" id="RID" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td>Event ID*</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="EID" id="EID" size="5" maxlength="5"/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
    <hr/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the PHP:**

```
<body>
<?php
  // access details as variables
  $username = "xxxx";
  $password = "tttt";
  $hostname = "rrrrr";
  //connection
  $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die ('connection problem:' . mysql_error());
  echo $connection . "CONNECTION SUCCEDED<br><br><br>";
  //select a database
  $mydb = mysql_select_db("xxxx", $connection)or die ('db problem:' . mysql_error());
  echo $mydb . " DB SELECTED <br><br><br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's a glaring syntax error in your "validate" function. Please make sure you've taken basic debugging steps like checking your browser's error console before posting questions.

Comment: Sorry, just a copy and paste mistake. My function should be syntactically correct as: {...&& validateEId(); return validated;}

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the javascript function

try this

```
function validate() 
{
    var validated = false;
    validated = validateRId() && validateEId() ;    
    return validated;
}
```

Comment: Hi,thank you. My mistake, my function is actually
{...&& validateEId(); return validated;}
As you corrected it. But the problem is always there...